# How to capture the errors traced to the console from StageWebView

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash-builder, stagewebview

When setting the content of a StageWebView to HTML markup that contains errors in JavaScript or HTML, those errors are traced to the console in Flash Builder. Is there a way to capture those errors?

For example, if I have a DIV and it is not terminated correctly this message is traced to the console,

```
about:blank:75 HTML ERROR: Unmatched </div2> encountered.  Ignoring tag.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can able capture the HTML / Javascript errors by using [StageWebViewBridge](https://code.google.com/p/stagewebviewbridge/), using this .swc when error occurs in your page, this will trace the error message in your flash builder console.

```
    private var _stage : Stage;

    private function added_to_stage_handler():void
    {
         _stage = this.stage;
         initStage();
    }
    private function initStage() : void
    {
        StageWebViewDisk.setDebugMode( true );
        StageWebViewDisk.initialize(stage);
    }

    private function loadURL( url : String ):void
    {
        if(!webView)
            webView = new StageWebViewBridge(0, 300, 900, 300);
        webView.addEventListener(StageWebViewBridgeEvent.DEVICE_READY, onDeviceReady );
        webView.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteHandler);
        webView.addEventListener(ErrorEvent.ERROR, onErrorHandler);
        webView.addEventListener(LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGING, onLocationChange);
        var _view:SpriteVisualElement = new SpriteVisualElement();
        _view.addChild(webView);
        addElement(_view);
        webView.loadURL( url );
    }
```